# Amfphp And Flex4.5 very simple login system

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am trying to create a login screen in flex and I am sending my variables through amfphp and when I run this query I get no returned data.

When I pass values to the browser of amfphp I can see that a row is returned. Can someone explain what I'm I doing wrong keep in mind that I am a total noob.

The errors that I have are:

> (Object)#0
>     message = "faultCode:INVALID_AMF_MESSAGE faultString:'Invalid AMF message' faultDetail:'' Rows:1
>     ''"
>     name = "Error"
>     rootCause = (null)

```
<?php
    require('connection.php');

    class NotWorking {

        private $dbc;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) OR DIE (mysqli_connect_error() );
        }

        public function no ($someVar) {
            $data = array();
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc,trim($someVar['password']));
            $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc,trim($someVar['email']));
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
            $r= mysqli_query($this->dbc,$query);

            /*
            if($r){
                echo ' query works ';
                var_dump($r);
            }else{ 
                echo 'Does not work';
            }
            */

            $num = mysqli_num_rows($r);
            echo "'Rows: $num'";

            if ($num > 0 )
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r) ){
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: test it using firefox and firebug, check your parameters and the return value - also check your sandbox

Comment: Don't have much context here but how do you do the mapping between your data object created in PHP and the Flex equivalent? If you call the no method of your NotWorking class from Flex with a RemoteObject then the echo could be the reason your code isn't working because you have an extra string being "sent" before your $data

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is to debug the traffic with [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).
I've had a brief look at your code and the one thing that jumps out at me is that you're `echo`ing a string in your method. amfPHP doesn't like this as it messes with the output buffering. If you remove that `echo`, your function should work; it depends on which version of amfPHP you're using.